# cp command not working in Bash Script in build pipeline of azure devops

Tags: linux, bash, macos, azure-devops, cp

I need to copy the folder with multiple files to another folder in build pipeline.

I use

```
cp -R -v pathToSourceFolder pathToDestFolder

cp -R -v   /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/en.lproj/  /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/platforms/ios/AppName/Resources
```

and I am getting error with exit code 126:

```
usage: cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file target_file
       cp [-R [-H | -L | -P]] [-fi | -n] [-apvXc] source_file ... target_directory
```

can anyone help with this as I am new to linux/macOS uses/cmd? 
Note: pipeline run on macOS.

Comment: Please don't provide screenshots, unless necessary for understanding, but post the command you have problem with as a text.

Comment: I thought i would be better to show issue ...should I  edit the question?

Comment: Definitely. If you really thing pictures help, you can post a link to a picture **in addition**. At the very least we need to see the command, which causes the error, as text (so it can be copied and pasted).

Comment: @user1934428 is it clear now? can you please answer the question?

Comment: I don't think that your directory is **really** named `pathToSourceFolder `. You need to post the command **exactly** as it is written in your shell script.

Comment: `pathToSourceFolder ` is just a way to say which is the source directory sir

Comment: Yes, if you do not say the **real** directories exactly as you wrote them, but we don't see whether it contains some special characters which, if not quoted properly, might cause the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213754/discussion-between-ragesh-pikalmunde-and-user1934428).

Comment: @user1934428 Hi friend, please consider adding your solution as answer since your script works well to resolve the original issue.(According to the latest news from the chat room above~) So that members with similar issue can find the useful info easily and we can archive this thread !  Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to copy the folder with multiple files to another folder in
>   build pipeline.

1.I assume `/Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s` is the default working folder of your build. So please avoid hard-coding the path, instead you can use `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)` which represents that path. See Azure Devops [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables).

2.Since your original purpose is to copy the files in Azure Devops pipeline, you don't need to care too much about the corresponding copy syntax in different OS systems (Linux,MacOS or Windows).

You can do what you want **easily** using official [Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). This task requires three inputs: `Source folder`, `Target folder` and `Contents` we want to copy, that's it.

**Classic UI format:**

[image]

You can choose the source folder via `Browse Source Folder` option. And then use `**` as Contents, `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Fixi/Resources` as Target folder.

**Yaml format:**

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'My Copy Task'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: en.lproj
    TargetFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Fixi/Resources'
```

We've done the logic in the behind for you so that you can use this task in MacOS/Linux/Windows easily. Log of my test:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. it helped to write paths properly.

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde You're welcome! And do you find the solution to your issue after the comments above? If so, consider adding it as answer and [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/515442). So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)

Comment: as mentioned in your answer...it only copy files from source folder to target folder...right??

do we have task to copy folder with its file from one location to another as I asked in question or this task work as excepted?

above accepted answer is working ...I just want to know for the personal knowledge.

Comment: @RageshPikalmunde Hmm, I think the task can do this also. Change the target folder input to `$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/platforms/ios/Fixi/Resources/en.lproj`, then the task will copy content in en.lproj folder(source) to the target en.lproj(if not exists, the task will create it for you). Note: The files are copied recursively when using this task. So in this way, the Copy Files Task will work like a 'Copy Folder task'. Hope it helps~

Answer (score 2):

Since there is nothing **obviously** wrong in the cp command, I would just write some safety checks about the presence of the directories:

```
# Define directories involved
from="pathToSourceFolder"
to="pathToDestFolder"

# Check existence
if [[ -d "$from" ]]
then
  # If the destination directory does not exist, we create it.
  [[ -d $to ]] || mkdir -p "$to"
  if [[ -d $to ]]
  then
    cp -R -v "$from" "$to"
  else
    # If we get here, we will likely have permission problems.
    echo Can not create directory $to
    ls -ld "$to"
  fi
else
  echo Source directory $from does not exist
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the accepted answer says the "cp" command is not broken, but it actually is in azure pipelines. Microsoft seems to append a "/" at the end by default, which breaks the behaviour of the command.

if you do:

```
cp -r ./src ./dest
```

it will copy the files from src folder to dest folder.

if you write:

```
cp -r ./src ./dest/
```

it will copy the src folder into the destination one leaving you with /dest/src/*

Also, my build pipeline failed when I tried to copy a file

```
cp ./src/myfile.txt ./dest/myfile.txt
```

Adding the "/" at the end will cause it to fail as it's attempting to dump the file into a directory that does not exist since the actual command that runs is the following.

```
cp ./src/myfile.txt ./dest/myfile.txt/
```